# How to delete line between div & svg

Tags: html, css, reactjs

**How to fix it?**
*the line between div and svg*

so the problem is, line, and i just started making wave svg, and i want to combine with div white

[the line, svg and div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Mse.png)
[image]

**this with pointer**

[image]

**second with pointer**

[image]

i want to solve this

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Both will tell you things you were told in the Ask Question Wizard; namely, provide code that reproduces the issue, a [mre].

Comment: Welcome! Would it be possible for you to provide a [Stack Snippet](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/11107541)? Note: Stack Snippets are preferred over links to external repros for reasons explained in [ask].